# Data warehouse from relational database and non relational

Tags: data-warehouse, non-relational-database

I am working on the case study, I have a question related to creating of data warehouse. However, it involves two organization one uses a relational database and other is non-relational database and both organization uses different CRM. what are the challenges can come up while creation and implementing data warehouse?

Comment: This is not a programming question. I vote that it be closed.  Also, too general of a question.

Comment: I've voted to close but consider this: the only way you'll arrive at any kind of answer is to be more specific. For example there could be technical challenges and non technical challenges. A technical challenge could be extracting data out of a non-relational source (by non relational due you mean a bunch of records in text file or a bunch of binary documents?). A non technical challenge could be getting the business to define meaningful metrics out of a non relational system.

Comment: Not a suitable question for stackoverflow. You'll have better luck at [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), [here](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [here](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Challenges are specific to the case. So if your organizations are geographically disparate then you have particular challenges around that at the business communication level even before think about designing the DW